# How do I read a XLSX if the filepath or filename has an apostrophe?

Tags: python, pandas, validation

I am trying to read in a XLSX file, but my filepath has an apostrophe. Are there any workarounds? Had to re-write, have a new error, see below:

```
df_siteData = pd.DataFrame()
df_siteData = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Ben.Dreyfuss\Documents\milly's\milly's- raw data.xlsx')

Error: File "<ipython-input-61-215e07fcbd29>", line 2
df_siteData = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Ben.Dreyfuss\Documents\milly's\milly's- raw data.xlsx')
                                                                   ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The error message itself tells you at what position it fails. It's not the apo'strophe.

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't with the apostrophe, it's with the backslash (`\`) character. It is being used simultaneously as a directory separator and as an escape character.

Try this:

```
pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Ben.Dreyfuss\Documents\milly's\milly's- raw data.xlsx")
```

It will either work or give you a different error.

Alternatively, you can take advantage of a Windows feature -- either flavor of slash works equally well as a directory separator. The following two are equivalent:

```
pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Ben.Dreyfuss/Documents/milly's/milly's- raw data.xlsx")
```

or

```
pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Ben.Dreyfuss/Documents/milly\'s/milly\'s- raw data.xlsx')
```

Comment: pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Ben.Dreyfuss/Documents/milly's/milly's- raw data.xlsx") --> that worked